# Does kala pani mean crossing the sea by boat or ship or does kala pani mean going to other countries for example, USA, how do i get forgiven for sin

Tags: sin

does kala pani mean crossing the sea by boat or ship or does kala pani mean going to other countries, for example, the USA, how do i get forgiven for kala pani fast

Comment: This question not related to this platform

Comment: The question which you are asking is not clear. Rephrase the question so we can understand. Moreover, I also don't think that it's related to this platform but maybe after rephrasing it becomes clear.